# Laravel - Validate birth date 18 years before today in rules request

Tags: laravel

In Laravel 8 form request validation's rules, I have this birth date validation:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'birth_date' => [
            'required',
            'before: date("Y-m-d")'
        ],
    ];
}
```

How do I validate it to be 18 years less than or equal to today's date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Carbon` (built in to Laravel):

```php
public function rules() {
  return [
    'birth_date' => [
      'required',
      'date_format:Y-m-d',
      'before:' . Carbon::now()->subYears(18)->format('Y-m-d')
    ],
  ];
}
```

This would generate `before:2003-07-30`. Make sure to include `use Carbon\Carbon;` at the top of this file, or do `Carbon\Carbon::now()->subYears(18)->format('Y-m-d');`

Comment: Thanks @TimLewis - How about if I want to validate it just less than today?

Comment: Same idea, `'before: ' . Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d')`  Or, you should be able to do `before:today` in later versions of Laravel.

Comment: Check for docs for Carbon: https://carbon.nesbot.com/, lots of useful methods for constructing dates/times

Comment: this is worked for me with before with after we can limit max and min date that user can select